# Setting up SVN Server on CentOS as a Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, centos, virtualhost

So, I've followed every tutorial I can find on Google and still can't get this to work. Below is the `subversion.conf` file I have in my `conf.d` folder of my server.

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/svn.example.com
        ServerName svn.example.com
        ServerAlias svn.example.com

        <Location /repo>
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath   /home/svn.example.com/repo
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I already installed subversion via yum as well as dav_svn.

I just want to access my repository without security yet...I'll add that shortly, but right now the result is that I get the default Apache HTTP Server Test Page that indicates the server is installed but there are no files in the directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## Intro

1. You have unfinished jobs on Apache and Subversion sides
2. In order to repositories after all you have to create at least one

## Details

Extraction from my Apache config for http-served repo (in "main site", but it does not matter in this case), edited for **your** paths

```
LoadModule dav_module mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module mod_dav_svn.so
...
<Directory />
...
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/repo$
  RewriteRule ^(.*/repo)$ %1/ [R=301,L]
</Directory>
<Location /repo/>
  DAV svn

  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath /home/svn.example.com/repo
```

- dav_module needed for dav_svn_module
- All repos will be under URL http://svn.example.com/repo/*, **not in root**, rewrite rule in root will redirect all requests from root to DAV-SVN served location.
- BTW - place repositories **inside web-space is bad idea** (security in mind), SVNParentPath can define place outside site. But I'll proceed with  your old path here
- `SVNListParentPath on` allow to [show listing of repos](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/) in ordinary browser
- Don't forget chmod|chgrp correctly repo root - Apache-user must have rights read-write into repos, you probably also want to have local access to repositories

Here Apache-side we can consider as finished (TBT!)

Subversion side:

- cd /home/svn.example.com/repo
- mkdir repo1
- svnadmin create /home/svn.example.com/repo/repo1
- repeat mkdir + svnadmin create for all needed repos

Final steps

- Check results by visiting in browser http://svn.example.com/repo/
- Checkout any (still empty) repo, add files, commit
- Have fun